# Is there a sleep() function for Android NDK?

Tags: c++, android, android-ndk

Under Android NDK, is there a sleep() function which sleeps for X miliseconds, but do not block the event loop?

We are writing API tests to work on Mac, Windows, and Android. So far, we have implemented some sort of sleep() for Mac and Windows, but we are all new to Android NDK and need some help there. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So you are looking for a `sleep()` method that does sleep for a certain amount of time but does not block the event loop? This sounds odd to me. I think you might want to use a new thread instead and call the sleep() method there - without having to use any JNI.

Comment: I should be more clear: I want to sleep, but do not block *other* processes. My own process should be blocked.

Comment: You *can't* block other processes.  They are...  other processes.  They don't depend on you running.  That said, using sleep() in an event loop is a strong indication of something being broken.

Comment: That shows how green I am to this platform. So, is there a sleep() function for Android?

Comment: @hai: Yes and yes. Sleep function in the Android SDK: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29  Sleep function for use in C/C++: `sleep(seconds)` or `usleep(microseconds)` (you will have to include <unistd.h>).

Comment: That should fix it. Thank you

Comment: That comment about #include <unistd.h> is so useful - would you consider updating your answer to include it?

Answer (score 13):

Turning @mreichelt commment into an answer:

Yes there is a `sleep(seconds)` function.

1. Add  `#include <unistd.h>`
2. Call:  `sleep(seconds)` or `usleep(microseconds)`

note: A microsecond (us or Greek letter mu plus s) is one millionth (10 -6 ) of a second, while a millisecond (ms or msec) is one thousandth of a second

Answer (score 3):

YES
it is defined in unistd.h But be careful sleep function is not standardized so on windows sleep which is defined in  
`
on windows

```
sleep(int millisenconds);
```

on linux`

```
int sleep(unsigned int seconds);
int usleep(useconds_t useconds);
```

usleep takes microseconds where sleep takes seconds. 1 second=1*1000*1000

Answer (score 2):

The normal linux sleep functions (usleep, etc) will block the thread that calls them.  It's up to you which thread that is - hopefully not the UI one.

A more android style approach would be to set up an event to happen at a future time and then return from the current event.  When the new event fires you take the next step.  Think for example of a state machine with each state being entered as an event, doing something effectively instantaneous, scheduling the next state for a future time, and then returning .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Handler.postDelayed][1] to schedule a Runnable to run after a set time, the event loop will continue to work in the meantime.

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)

Comment: +1, on the basis that scheduling a timed event is probably the right answer to the real question

Comment: It is the right approach for Android apps written in Java. But Hai wanted to know how to sleep in a C++ program without blocking the program which only can be done using multiple threads.